# Snap to Midpoint

Tags: workflow, edit-mode, snapping

Is in Blender has ability to snap to midpoint without any additional manipulations like cutting or some else?

Like this in 3ds Max.

[image]

I found that " Knife tool " has midpoint snap when holding Ctrl key.

[image]

So it looks like there was a way to find the midpoint. But when I use edge snap and holding Ctrl while edit something it does not snap to midpoint it just stop snap. Maybe it need to press or hold some other key or keys to snap like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Blender 2.81 and newer [mid point snapping for mesh edges](https://developer.blender.org/rB58341242bf6b30392435130b242d2366ab03c1dd) is available from the *Snap Popover* in the *3D View* header.

For older versions or whenever the intended mid point is between two different objects or otherwise not over a mesh edge, a possible workaround is to use Blenders *Mark Multiple Snap Targets* feature to simulate a midpoint.

This is a relatively obscure feature, to use it automatic snapping must be turned on by having the magnet icon active, also make sure set it to *Vertex* and *Closest*.

This way while transforming you will no longer need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap to other vertex. That leaves you free to press <kbd>A</kbd> while inside transform modal operators to "acquire targets" for snapping.

If you hover two different points (at the end of the same edge or even different objects altogether) and press <kbd>A</kbd> while each vertex is highlighted, one at a time, it will effectively snap to the midpoint of those two elements.

Before you confirm transform make sure you are hovering no other snap target at all (including the previously selected ones) or it will average the snap midpoint considering those as well.

[image]

More about it in [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html?highlight=snapping#multiple-snap-targets)

Comment: Hmm ... Thank you. It works. But it still does not allow to snap to midpoint of edge that adjoining to one of editable vertex.
Why it's so "exclusive" just and only for knife tool? Is there some important reason?
Did developers never seen how it work in Max or Modo or if they seen did not they notice that some things was comfortable and useful? And there is no need to do something 180 degrees different way.

Comment: Blender snap system is aging and some serious overhaul is overdue. Knife tool on the other had is relatively recent and modern in comparison.