# snap element, snap to vertex OR edge (both)

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to make the "snap element" be both vertex AND edge?

In the tutorial I'm following I need to stitch two different objects together. I do this manually by adjusting the vertices of object A to either the vertices or the edges of object B.

Currently I'm constantly switching from snap element=vertex to snap element=edge, which takes me about 1sec every time (and there are a lot of vertices..) and it would greatly improve my workflow if blender could just snap to whatever my mouse encounters (edge OR vertice).

An add-on maybe?

Comment: could you please show a screenshot of your mesh? are there not other solutions like bridge or grid fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment, as far as I know.

Multi target snap has been introduced in [New Feature Proposal: Mixed Snap in 3d View.](https://developer.blender.org/D3400) by Germano Cavalcante, and is planned for the upcoming 2.8 releases.

For the time being as a workaround you may try [multi point snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80760/snap-to-midpoint)